# What's the difference between depth + 1 and depth++ in this DFS recursion function?

Tags: java, recursion, depth-first-search

I'm doing leetcode, and got in this confusion since the result of depth++ and depth+1 is totally different! I thought they were the same before. Can anyone explain the difference between them?

```
private void dfs(TreeNode root, List<Integer> res, int depth) {
    if (root == null) return;
    if (res.size() == depth) {
        res.add(root.val);
    } 
    dfs(root.right, res, depth + 1); // depth++ would get different result
    dfs(root.left, res, depth + 1);
}
```

Comment: `depth++;` the addition is "post" operation. `++depth;` and it is "pre". That is why they are called the "post" and "pre" increment operators.

Comment: What's the difference between `depth + 1` and `depth++` *outside* the function?  Seriously, you can answer this yourself.

Comment: `depth++` increments `depth` after the call. It is the *post* increment operator. You can do `++depth` to get equivalent results to `depth + 1`

Comment: But as long as we're answering here, note that although `++depth` would evaluate to the same result as `depth + 1`, but  those aren't equivalent either, because the former produces a side effect on `depth` that the latter does not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**depth++** is the same as `depth=depth+1` . The increment operator will modify and returns the copy of old `depth`.

```
int x = depth;
depth = depth+1;
return x;
```

**depth+1** operation will return the value of expression without any modification.

```
return depth+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

**if you are using post increment with assignment**

```
int a=1;
a = a++;
```

- You can think this way (a=a++ => a=a and then a++)
- Now when we assign [a=a++] a = 1 during assignment and after assignment a=2

**if you are using post increment without assignment**

```
int x=1;
x++;
```

- Now x = 2 during assignment and x=2 after assignment also

Answer (score 0):

The *post* increment operator `varName++` uses the *current* value, *then* increments the variable, *then* continues executing the rest of the statement.

If you used the *pre* increment operator `++varName`, the first call would work as it does with `depth + 1`, *but* would leave the variable incremented, requiring the *next* usage of it to factor this in:

```
dfs(root.right, res, ++depth); // increment before using value
dfs(root.left, res, depth); // depth already incremented
```

Although this would execute a very tiny amount faster due to avoiding 1 arithmetic operation, the code is harder to read and could lead to bugs if more code was added that did not expect `depth` to change within the method.

Some consider changing the value of method parameters poor style, although this style guideline is not universally accepted as best practice.

Answer (score 0):

`depth + 1` and `depth++` are the same as result, but the way they are performed is different.
`depth = depth + 1` applies the calculation results to the next operation.
`depth++` First, performs an operation to the pre-addition value and then adds one.